# loop Redux option framework repeater field

Tags: loops, redux, foreach

how can show the this array with foreach ?
this is out put of reapeter redux freamwork
please help me

```
array(3) {
  ["redux_repeater_data"]=&gt;
  array(1) {
    [0]=&gt;
    array(1) {
      ["title"]=&gt;
      string(0) ""
    }
  }
  ["picturelink"]=&gt;
  array(1) {
    [0]=&gt;
    string(74) "https://demo.mizwp.com/hamyar/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/insta-banner.webp"
  }
  ["linktoslider"]=&gt;
  array(1) {
    [0]=&gt;
    string(4) "asas"
  }
}
```

i use this code but not working

```
$slides = $tt_data['slide-repeater'];

foreach ( $slides as $slide ):

echo $slide['picturelink']['url'];


endforeach;
```

i use the foreach loop but is not working